# SELECT DISTINCT picture, ID from Table

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I need to be able to select 3 distinct picture URL's held in the database but also pull the other data in the row without it affecting the DISTINCT argument...

EXAMPLE::

DataBase =

```
ID - PICTURE_URL
01 - domain.com/pic1.jpg
02 - domain.com/pic1.jpg
03 - domain.com/pic1.jpg
04 - domain.com/pic2.jpg
05 - domain.com/pic3.jpg
```

So in the above example the SQL should only PULL either ID 1, 2, or 3 as a result, and 4 & 5 as the other 2 results.

OUTPUT =

```
01 Domain.com/pic1.jpg
04 Domain.com/pic2.jpg
05 Domain.com/pic3.jpg
```

OR

```
02 Domain.com/pic1.jpg
04 Domain.com/pic2.jpg
05 Domain.com/pic3.jpg
```

OR

```
03 Domain.com/pic1.jpg
04 Domain.com/pic2.jpg
05 Domain.com/pic3.jpg
```

Because picture_url all had the same url to a picture stored on the server, so I do not want to select the same 3 pictures.

:)

Any help on this would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Why you interested in ID when you need to get distinct url-s?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate function:

```
select min(ID), PICTURE_URL
from your_table
group by PICTURE_URL
```

Comment: That put me on the right tracks, 'group by' seemed to work for what I needed... What is the min(ID) doing? Can you explain it please because I'm not sure if I should use it.

Comment: What the query does is this: For each PICTURE_URL take the smallest ID found. 

This would give you output:
01 Domain.com/pic1.jpg
04 Domain.com/pic2.jpg
05 Domain.com/pic3.jpg

You could as well take max(ID), in that case the "Domain.com/pic1.jpg" would get value of "03" which is the biggest ID for that URL.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I ended up using this query `code` SELECT DISTINCT id,title,picture,general_url
FROM adverts
WHERE status != 'pending'
GROUP BY picture
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3 ; `code`

Comment: Sorry dont know how to get that to display code properly, neither can I vote up yet...

Comment: Why not just use valid SQL? Will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: Hey @slaakso if you are not prepared to add value to the post by giving explanations or examples so people can learn from you, best just hush it.

Comment: Sorry not explaining my answer properly (thought I already did). The initial answer alongside the explanation I gave to you, while trying to help you, was valid SQL, short and efficient answer to your original question.
The problems the the code you chose were: 1) Use of GROUP BY without aggregate function 2) ORDER BY logic is  
obscure 3) LIMIT causes false result if you have more than 3 picture URL's. 
It is of course you who chooses what code you use.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you caught me at a bad moment, I do apologize my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6e4b/4)**

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.PICTURE_URL
FROM Table1 t1
left join Table1 t2
on t1.PICTURE_URL = t2.PICTURE_URL
AND t1.ID > t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID is null
```

Result:

```
| ID |         PICTURE_URL |
|----|---------------------|
|  1 | domain.com/pic1.jpg |
|  4 | domain.com/pic2.jpg |
|  5 | domain.com/pic3.jpg |
```